# OnConfigurationChanged is reloading my contentview

Tags: android, android-layout, configuration, orientation

I've been trying to set my activity so that the content view won't change even if the device orientation is being changed. The thing is, that whenever I change the orientation (whether from portrait to landscape or from landscape to portrait), the layout is refreshed, and it's re-loaded.
I want to prevent my layout of being refreshed. How can I accomplish that task?

Here's the onConfigurationChanged method:

```
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        Log.d(Global.TAG, "LANDSCAPE");
    }
    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
         Log.d(Global.TAG, "PORTRAIT");
    }

}
```

Here's the manifest of my activity:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.inturnex.safecam.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with the layout being refreshed?  Android is designed to behave that way.  Tell us what the root issue is and we can probably suggest a solution.

Comment: @CollinFlynn Is the layout supposed to get refreshed? I want my layout to be exactly the same when the orientation is changed.

Comment: What's the target and min/max SDK declared in the ManifesT?

Comment: are you sure that you activity is reloaded? shown an alert, change your screen orientation if the alert disappears means is been reloaded.

Comment: @idish Yes, the intended behavior is to reconstruct the layout when transitioning between landscape and portrait.  If this causes awkward data loss or state changes in your views or their contents, you should use the life cycle methods to handle that.

Comment: @g00dy min sdk - 9 target sdk - 18

Comment: @CollinFlynn I'll give you an example. in my original layout, there is a linearlayout located in the bottom of the screen. When the orientation changes, the linearlayout gets to the bottom again, but I want it to be in the same position as before.. I don't understand what should I do in order to keep the layout as it is. Like, when I change the orientation, I don't want anything to move.

Comment: @idish - try putting only `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`, I see everywhere that for API 13 and above the people use just that.

Comment: Also, MinSDK is 9, target is 18, what about the maxSDK and the API level of the device you're running this on ?

Comment: @g00dy I tried your idea, doesn't work and I haven't set the maxSDK, is it important?

Comment: @idish If you have the LinearLayout configured to be at the bottom of the screen, it will move to the bottom because that **is** the same position as far as Android is aware.  If you'd like the linearLayout to not be at the bottom of the screen after a screen rotation, you can define both a landscape and portrait xml and Android will automatically use the appropriate one based on the orientation at runtime.

Comment: @CollinFlynn This is the answer I was looking for, thank you. You can post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `LinearLayout` configured to be at the bottom of the screen, it will move to the bottom because that is the same position as far as Android is aware. If you'd like the `LinearLayout` to not be at the bottom of the screen after a screen rotation, you can define both a landscape and portrait xml and Android will automatically use the appropriate one based on the orientation at runtime.

[Here is the relevant developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) on how to tell Android which layout to use.

Comment: I have a question: If I set my activity to be available only in portrait mode, is it possible to detect if the user is looking at the device in landscape mode?

Comment: There is still a loading process when loading the other layout. I'll try to tell you exactly what I want.

Comment: Let's take the camera application. When you switch from portrait mode to landscape mode. You don't see any change but only the rotation of some views are being rotated. They don't load another xml layout. Do you have any idea how can I do that?

Comment: I'm sorry for misleading you. I still cannot accept this as an answer.